# Rapidjson does not encode utf8 sequence at all

Tags: c++, json, utf-8, rapidjson

I'm trying to use rapidjson to escape utf8 sequences to `\uXXXX` format, but it's not working.

```
StringBuffer s;
Writer<StringBuffer, Document::EncodingType, ASCII<> > writer(s);
writer.StartObject();
writer.String("chinese");
writer.String("中文测试");
writer.EndObject();
cout << s.GetString() << endl;
```

The document says it would be escaped but actually it's all erased.

I tried to use AutoUTF template, but [here's no document for memory stream either](http://miloyip.github.io/rapidjson/md_doc_stream.html#AutoUTFOutputStream)

Any ideas? I tried jsoncpp as well, but that library does not support unicode as well

Thanks @Milo Yip, I forget to mention I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 2):

I tried on OS X and it works:

```
{"chinese":"\u4E2D\u6587\u6D4B\u8BD5"}
```

I think the problem is that, the compiler you are using does not encode the literal string `"中文测试"` into UTF-8. Linux/OSX treats source code as UTF-8 but Windows does not by default.

You can try to use C++11 UTF-8 literal `u8"中文测试"`. Or you can read the strings from a UTF-8 encoded file for testing.

---

The question was updated. On Visual Studio 2010 and after, there is an undocumented feature:

```
#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")
```

Such that the literal characters are encoded in UTF-8. For C++11 compatible compilers, `u8"xxx"` literal should be used.

Anyway, the claim that "Rapidjson does not encode utf8 sequence at all" is incorrect.

Comment: Oh I was running Visual Studio 2010, will add that to the post