# RapidJSON: Write with string with Chinese characters

Tags: c++, writer, wstring, rapidjson

I generated the following JSON using C++:

```
{
    "ProfileID": "DUO1",
    "ProfileName": "Sample"
}
```

The code used for generating that is:

```
string jsonData = "";
StringBuffer sb;
PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer(sb);

writer.StartObject();
writer.Key("ProfileID");
writer.String(strProfileId.c_str());

writer.Key("ProfileName");                  
writer.String(strName.c_str());

writer.EndObject();
jsonData = sb.GetString();
```

It is working fine for ProfileName in English. If the profile name is in another language (say Chinese), how can this be done?

I want generate JSON like this:

```
{
    "ProfileID": "DUO1",
    "ProfileName": "不用客气"
}
```

I was able to set this Chinese name in `wstring`.

How to write this correctly to JSON?

Comment: See: [String and Character Literals (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

RapidJSON [supports UTF-8 by default](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_encoding.html). I am guessing the problem is with your compiler rather than with RapidJson. On linux, gcc treats source code as UTF-8, but on Windows MSVC does not.

On VS2008, [you can change this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696627/how-to-set-standard-encoding-in-visual-studio) on `Tools > Options > Environment > Documents` and checking `Save documents as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage`.
On VS2010 and later, [you can specify the encoding on a per-file basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860029/rapidjson-does-not-encode-utf8-sequence-at-all) with the pragma `#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")`.

You can then write things such as `writer.String(u8"不用客气");`.

Comment: thanks. I will try this option. This code should work in both Windows and MAC. For windows VS 2017 IDE and for MAC xCode IDE we are using

Comment: I've tried the above solution. writer.String((u8)strName.c_str()); it is showing u8 undefined. If i use  writer.String((u8)"不用客气"). It is storing in ascii only.

Comment: If i use, writer.String((u8)"不用客气") i am getting the below: {
    "outputprofileid": "ICCFDUP1",
    "colorprofilename": "ä¸ç”¨å®¢æ°”"
}

Comment: @preethiselvaraju: What editor do you use for viewing JSON file? Notepad++? Visual Studio? This may be just an editor decoding problem.

Comment: Am using Visual Studio 2017 IDE.If i use  writer.String(u8"不用客气"), it is working fine. But how to code  by passing variable name. strProfileName has the chinese name. writer.String(strProfileName). If i use writer.String((u8)strProfileName.c_str()) it is throwing error.

Comment: It seems you think `u8` is a [cast operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), but it actually is a [string literal prefix](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). How you get UTF-8 into a `string` (or `wstring`) is another question, however, and [can be platform-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring). It is not really related to RapidJSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature for PrettyWritter.

```
template<typename Stream, typename Encoding = UTF8<>, typename Allocator = MemoryPoolAllocator<> >
class PrettyWriter : public Writer<Stream, Encoding, Allocator>
{...}
```

It takes Encoding as its second template parameter.
By default it is UTF8<> which is const char*.
You have to use multibyte encoding to support multiple languages.
RapidJson Supports UTF8<>, UTF16<> and UTF32<> encodings.

By specifying UTF16<> as second template parameter for PrettyWriter object in your code should solve your issue. But you will need to use std::wstring instead of std::string and const wchar_t* instead of const char* for all strings where you expect different language.